# Application.OnKey only for right ctrl in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

Is there any way to apply `Application.Onkey` method only on right (or left) ctrl (or alt, shift) key. I have been reading documentation and can not find it. Code will be run in Excel 2016.

Comment: `If {rightCtrl is not pressed} then exit sub`?